# Minimum cost tree.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees, discrete-optimization

I want an algorithm for the following problem. I have not find anything useful so far.

Given a undirected graph with costs assigned to the nodes, a positive number $n$ and a subset $S$ of the nodes, find a minimal cost subgraph with $n$ nodes that is connected and contains $S$. (If no such graph exists the algorithm should detect this.)

Is there such an algorithm? I know algorithms for spanning trees (Kruskal, Prim) but dont see a way to easily modify those.

Useful special cases or variants that I could have use for even if the entire problem is solved:

1. The set $S$ contains just one node.
2. The cost is zero for every node (that is we look for one solution ignoring the cost).
3. The cost is assigned to the edges instead of to the nodes.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem

Comment: Thanks RobPratt. It is probably no simple solution then.